# Unable to write a file to the server

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service that creates files on the server. It works great locally. As soon as I deploy the service to the shared host, it hangs. No exception is caught in the front end web site. When I inspect the folder where it should have written a file, I see the file written with 0 bytes.

Is this a permissions issue?

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT: The exception I get is:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

Comment: Can you supply the code? It may be there is an issue initializing the file stream, or a failure to close the file stream in your code that works when the worker process closes out on your local machine, but never reaches that point on the hosted server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's about permissions. Because you can create a file. I think your issue is about getting the data that will be written into the file. If you're posting a file into server, maybe your [max request length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) is exceeding.

Comment: I added the <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"/> in the web.config but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

There are separate create and modify permissions in windows.  You could be creating the file but not able to write to it but that would be unusual. Remember that the ID running the webserver needs permissions not you.